# Failed to retrieve Adobe Stock search files results when opening media gallery in the Admin Panel

Tags: magento2.4.2, adobe-stock

We get the following error logged when trying to access the gallery in the admin panel:

```
Failed to retrieve Adobe Stock search files results: Client error: `GET https://stock.adobe.io/Rest/Media/1/Search/Files?......` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
```

But we disabled the function:

```
$ n98-magerun2 config:store:get "*adobe*"
+---------------------------------+---------+----------+-------+
| Path                            | Scope   | Scope-ID | Value |
+---------------------------------+---------+----------+-------+
| adobe_stock/integration/enabled | default | 0        | 0     |
+---------------------------------+---------+----------+-------+
```

Why is that error happening?

EDIT:

It looks like this if we click insert image on A CMS page - I believe on the left side there should be the folder list as it was before the update to Magento Version 2.4.2 (from 2.3):

[image: Gallery]

EDIT2:

**Background / Essence of the question:** This Adobe stock integration seems to be new in version 2.4.2 and causing errors. We don't want to use it anyways, and believe it shouldn't cause errors if it's disabled.

Comment: can you attach a screenshot or explain how are you trying to access the gallery, please?

Comment: @DianaBotean Done

Comment: uhmm, maybe i am missing something. what update are you talking about?

Comment: @DianaBotean: I mean that before we used 2.4.2 and the new gallery (we were on 2.3) before, we did not have that problem

Comment: hmm ok... the upgrade itself should not disable the configuration, unless explicitly told so. that's weird..

Comment: I believe before the AdobeStock integration did not even exist. We also don't want to use it. The question is, how to properly disable it.

Comment: Have you found anything?

Comment: Not really, do you have the same problem? But we found that on some dev servers it seems to work?

Comment: We are thinking now about removing the adobe stock integration completely, like they do it here: https://packagist.org/packages/yireo/magento2-replace-all

Answer (score 1):

In the end of the day it was another problem.

The Amasty PageSpeed Optimizer module created 11 Mio files in /media which the Gallery tried to load. I think the module somehow excludes that folder normally, but as we uninstalled it, it couldn't any more.